# Como Incluir e manipular arquivo JSON local?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Eu utilizo de dados JSON para criar os `<options>` de um `<select>`:

```
jsonOptions.forEach(function(item) {                
  var option = document.createElement('option');
  option.text = item.description;
  option.value = item.product;
  dataList.appendChild(option);           
});
```

Mas estou achando muito feio ter isso dentro do código, montei este primeiro para ver se funcionava, até mesmo porque este JSON terá quase 2000 itens.

Então salvei meu JSON em um arquivo separado e tentei incluir um arquivo externo da seguinte forma:

```
[ 
    {"description": "Carro 1"},
    {"description": "Carro 2", "product": "4"},
    {"description": "Carro 3", "product": "4"},
    {"description": "Carro 4", "product": "4"},
    {"description": "Carro 5", "product": "4"},
    {"description": "Carro 6", "product": "4"}
]

$.getJSON("js/carros.json", function(item) {
  var option = document.createElement('option');
  option.text = item.description;
  option.value = item.product;
  dataList.appendChild(option);
});
```

Além da forma correta de salvar o arquivo e chamá-lo, outra dúvida que possuo é para com a chamada da biblioteca jQuery.

Eu preciso chamar ela dentro do JavaScript que estou executando o código ou o fato dela estar presente lá no HTML significa que a mesma já foi carregada?

Dando continuidade as respostas dadas, surgiu algumas dúvidas com relação ao algoritmo.

```
$.getJSON('js/carros.json', function(err, data) {
  if (err !== null) {
    console.log('Ocorreu um erro' + err);
  } else {
    alert("chegou aqui!")
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

Estou usando este código, e o está apresentando o erro na Console:

```
jquery-2.1.0.js:8556 Failed to load file:///C:/Users/Alexandre/Desktop/Projeto%20Colet%C3%A2nea/New/js/carros.json: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
```

Verificando o caminho onde está o arquivo JSON, está correto.

Outra dúvida que me surgiu, onde encaixo o `forEach`?

Comment: Esta usando alguma lib ou somente js?

Comment: Estou utilizando jQuery, Select2 e Bootstrap.

Comment: Como edito minha pergunta?

Comment: Tem um botão editar logo em baixo das tags, que abre [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/268692/edit) Alexandre

Comment: Não estou entendo porque ele diz que não é compatível, o caminho está correto.

Comment: Você deveria estar usando um servidor local, como por exemplo o **Wamp** ou **Xampp**. Por isso esta com o erro **Cross origin**.

Comment: Entendo, mas eu tenho necessidade de utilizar um servidor local para qualquer algoritmo? Digo, a ideia do programa que estou trabalhando é ser pequeno! Não faz sentido colocar um Wamp só para gerar uma boa prática de programação.. Pelo menos é o que penso.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Caso você não queria utilizar `JQuery` pode acessar o arquivo utilizando [XMLHttpRequest()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Usando_XMLHttpRequest):

```js
var getJSON = function(url, callback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', url, true);
    xhr.responseType = 'json';
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      var status = xhr.status;
      if (status === 200) { 
        //Callback caso de tudo certo
        callback(null, xhr.response);
      } else {
        //Callback caso de algum erro
        callback(status, xhr.response);
      }
    };
    xhr.send();
};

//Utilizando o método
getJSON('SeuArquivo.json', function(err, data) {
  if (err !== null) {
    console.log('Ocorreu um erro' + err);
  } else {
    //Aqui você manipula os dados e pode percorrer e jogar no HTML 
    //da forma que achar mais adequada.
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

Caso queria utilizar a biblioteca `jquery` você deve incluir a biblioteca:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

E após o carregamento da página você pode acessar o arquivo através do método [getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/):

```js
//OnLoad
$(function(){

  $.getJSON("SeuArquivo.json", function(data) {
    //Aqui você manipula os dados e pode percorrer e jogar no HTML 
    //da forma que achar mais adequada.
      console.log(data); 
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Engraçado que pra mim está dando o seguinte erro no console `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nomedavariavel' of null` e mesmo assim sai a o valor da variável logo abaixo. Como pode estar dando erro e ao mesmo tempo retornando o valor?

Comment: Desculpe a demora, @ed1nh0 não consigo dizer sem ver seu código. Tente abrir uma pergunta nova no stackoverflow com ele, qualquer coisa manda o link dela aqui e eu tento te ajudar.

Comment: Caique Romero eu fiz de um jeito aqui que deu certo:

`function loadJSON(url, callback) {
     let xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xobj.overrideMimeType('application/json');
 xobj.open('GET', url, true);
 xobj.onreadystatechange = () => {
  if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == '200') callback(xobj.responseText);
 };
 xobj.send(null);
}`

Answer (score 3):

Com javascript puro pode-se ler usando *XMLHttpRequest* (sim, para ler JSON). Primeiro crie um arquivo `.json` para usar umas das funções. Exemplo:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "meu_json.json"; // caminho do arquivo

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var myArr = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        handle(myArr);
    }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();

function handle(arr) {
    // forEach aqui para criar o select
}
```

Ou mais facilmente com jQuery pode-se utlizar a função [$.getJSO](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)N:

```
// onde ajax/meu_json.json é o caminho do arquivo
$.getJSON( "ajax/meu_json.json", function( data ) {
  // forEach aqui para criar o select a partir de data
});
```

Comment: Utilizando o exemplo XMLHttpRequest, também aparece: 

Failed to load file:///C:/Users/Alexandre/Desktop/Projeto%20Colet%C3%A2nea/New/js/carros.json: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Answer (score 1):

A resposta enviada por todos estão corretas, o que não foi citado e que é o problema do meu código é que não utilizo um servidor local.

Este é um modelo de algoritmo que resolve o problema para quem TEM o servidor local como Wamp.

```
$.getJSON('js/carros.json', function(err, data) {
  if (err !== null) {
    console.log('Ocorreu um erro' + err);
  } else {
    alert("chegou aqui!")
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

Vou encerrar o tópico pois ficou parado, agradeço a todos que participaram e deram atenção, infelizmente vou procurar se existe maneira de se trabalhar sem o servidor, pois em meu caso é inviável, caso contrário, vou manter o JSON dentro do meu arquivo mesmo. Muito obrigado.

Answer (score -2):

Exemplo:

```
const fs = require('fs')

const produto = {
    nome: 'Produto',
    preco: 1249.99,
    desconto: 0.15
}

fs.writeFile(__dirname + '/arquivoGerado.json', JSON.stringify(produto), err => {
    console.log(err|| 'Arquivo salvo!')
})
```

Comment: Considere incluir uma breve explicação a respeito da sua resposta.