# Exibir dados de um arquivo Json em HTML

Tags: javascript, html, json, post, filtro

Estou empacado em uma situação onde eu não consigo transformar os blocos de dados do arquivo JSON em HTML, não aparece nada. Abaixo colocarei os códigos para vocês darem uma olhada

OBS: Se puderem me indicar um site legal sobre JSON também preciso saber sobre filtrar e adicionar posts, pois cada bloco JSON é um.

**UPDATE DO PROBLEMA**

Pessoal fiz abaixo os updates da resolução que tive para mostrar o conteúdo JSON no HTML, agora só falta o fazer o filtro que tem que ser a partir de dados como popularidade, Data e comentário, vou seguir a ajuda do amigo e se conseguir faço mais um update por aqui!!

**Código HTML(UPDATE)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="dados.json"> </script>
</head>
<body>
    <header><input id="filtro" type="text" placeholder="Busca Rápida"></header>
    <main id= "dados" ></main>
    <footer></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

**CÓDIGO DO FILTRO EM JAVASCRIPT(funcionando)**

```
<script>
$('#filtro').keyup(function () {
    var yourtext = $(this).val();
    if (yourtext.length > 0) {
        var abc = $("section").filter(function () {
            var str = $(this).text();
            var re = new RegExp(yourtext, "i");
            var result = re.test(str);
            if (!result) {
                return $(this);
            }
        }).hide();
    } else {
        $("section").show();
    }
});
</script>
```

**Arquivo JSON(UPDATE)**

```
window.onload=function(){
data = { person: [ 
    { 
    author: 'Nobtaka Nukui',
    title: 'Want people to use your product? Use it yourself',
    url: 'http://www.medium.com',
    category: 'Product Design',
    comments: '4 coments',
    created_at: '43 minutos atrás',
    classcor: 'corUm',
    foto: '<img src="img/ft-3.jpg" width="18" height="18" alt="Personagem1">',
    upvotes: 11 },
  {
    author: "Danil Ishutin",
    title: "Font Size Idea: px at Root, rem for Components, em for Text Elements",
    url: "http://www.css-tricks.com",
    category: "UX Theory",
    comments: '7 coments',
    created_at: '5 minutos atrás',
    classcor: 'corDois',
    foto: '<img src="img/ft-2.jpg" width="18" height="18" alt="Personagem2">',
    upvotes: 9},
    {
    author: "Kenny Schrub",
    title: "Some things cant be prototyped",
    url: "http://www.mika.el",
    category: "Opinion",
    comments:'25 coments',
    created_at: '7 minutos atrás',
    classcor: 'corTres',
    foto: '<img src="img/ft-2.jpg" width="18" height="18" alt="Personagem2">',
    isOwner: true,
    upvotes: 4  
        },
    {
    author: "Jacky Mao",
    title: "How to prototype without any tools",
    url: "http://www.jackymao.wix",
    category: "Opinion",
    comments: '0 coments',
    classcor: 'corTres',
    foto: '<img src="img/ft-1.jpg" width="18" height="18" alt="Personagem2">',
    upvotes: 4
        },

    {
    author: "Christopher Alesund",
    title: "Case study: Redesigning the Folyo landing page",
    url: "http://www.medium.com",
    category: "Case Study",
    comments: '0 coments',
    classcor: 'corQuatro',
    foto: '<img src="img/ft-1.jpg" width="18" height="18" alt="Personagem2">',
    created_at: '7 hours ago',
    upvotes: 3
  },
  {
    author: "Pasha Biceps",
    title: "Don't let bad process or structure kill great interfaces",
    url: "http://www.medium.com",
    category: 'Product Design',
    comments: '0 coments',
    classcor: 'corUm',
    foto: '<img src="img/ft-3.jpg" width="18" height="18" alt="Personagem2">',
    created_at: '2 days ago',
    isOwner: true,
    upvotes: 2
  }

    ]};

data.person.forEach(function(p){ 

  var post = "<section><span><a href='#'></a>"+p.upvotes+"</span><div><a     href="+p.url+">"+p.url+"</a><h1>"+p.title+"</h1><nav><a  href='#' id='bt-category' class="+ p.classcor +" title="+ p.category +">"+p.category+"</a><p>"+p.foto+"<a href='#' title="+p.author+">"+p.author+"</a>"+p.created_at+"<a  href='#' class='coments'>"+p.comments+"</a></p></nav></div></section>";

  document.querySelector('#dados').innerHTML += post;

});
}
```

Comment: Brother, qual a sua dúvida sobre Json? JSON é um array de objetos. Se você der um console.log na variável data o verá em seu estado original e aí poderá percorrê-lo sem dificuldade.

Comment: Assim é por que eu estou aprendendo JSON, e me deram isso pra fazer, eu pesquisei em tudo quando é lugar pra ver exemplos e o único que deu certo foi um com tabela, mas quando eu tento reproduzir o mesmo com HTML não dá certo, desculpa a nubisse!!

Comment: imagina... Olha, primeiro entenda o seguinte. JSON é um formato. Ou seja, uma forma de armazenar dados. Poderia ser por exemplo o XML. Sabendo disso, vou tentar jogar um exemplo aqui de Json como resposta e você adapta o seu blz?

Comment: blz, vlw mesmo, pois estou perdidão heheh

Comment: O problema está na atribuição do valor a variável `postRow`. Tens aspas simples onde deverias ter aspas duplas, não tem o `;` no fim. Isso tudo gera erros e por isso não é renderizado nada.

Comment: vc diz ali nas tags de link? pq foi o único jeito que o dreamweaver não acusou erro

Comment: Coloquei uma resposta abaixo, focando numa outra forma de consumir o JSON, que pelo que vi é sua dificuldade. Acho que é mais fácil de entender assim...

Comment: na linha onde tens `var postRow = `. O seu problema não é só entender como o JSON funciona e sim programação em si.

Comment: @FilipeMoraes  Se vc se refere ao espaço, é que eu dei um enter ali, mas mesmo sem ele não da certo

Comment: Eu recentemente escolhi usar o VueJS e o AXIOS, pode dar uma olhada nesta resposta para ver como tudo fica simples https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/308311/5704

Answer (score 2):

Veja que é um exemplo bem simples e que pode ser utilizado de diversas formas...

```js
var json = {
   person: [
   {
  "author": "Nobtaka Nukui",
  "title": "Want people to use your product? Use it yourself",
  "url": "http://www.medium.com",
  "category": "Product Design",
  "comments": 4,
  "created_at": 1460030400,
  "upvotes": 11
},
{
  "author": "Danil Ishutin",
  "title": "Font Size Idea: px at Root, rem for Components, em for Text Elements",
  "url": "http://www.css-tricks.com",
  "category": "ux_ui",
  "comments": 7,
  "created_at": 1459857600,
  "upvotes": 9
},
{
  "author": "Mikael Greif",
  "title": "What do you do with a failed project?",
  "url": "http://www.mika.el",
  "category": "discussion",
  "comments": 2,
  "created_at": 1460203200,
  "upvotes": 4
},
{
  "author": "Kenny Schrub",
  "title": "Some things can't be prototyped",
  "url": "http://www.mika.el",
  "category": "discussion",
  "comments": 25,
  "created_at": 1460203200,
  "isOwner": true,
  "upvotes": 4
},
{
  "author": "Jacky Mao",
  "title": "How to prototype without any tools",
  "url": "http://www.jackymao.wix",
  "category": "product_design",
  "comments": 0,
  "upvotes": 1
},
{
  "author": "Christopher Alesund",
  "title": "Case study: Redesigning the Folyo landing page",
  "url": "http://www.medium.com",
  "category": "case_study",
  "comments": 0,
  "created_at": 1460289600,
  "upvotes": 3
},
{
  "author": "Pasha Biceps",
  "title": "Don't let bad process or structure kill great interfaces",
  "url": "http://www.medium.com",
  "category": "product_design",
  "comments": 0,
  "created_at": 1460376000,
  "isOwner": true,
  "upvotes": 2
  }
 ]
};

//console.log(json);
for(var i=0;i< json.person.length; i++){
  var html = "<tr>";
  html +="<td>"+json.person[i].author+"</td>";
  html +="<td>"+json.person[i].title+"</td>";
  html +="<td>"+json.person[i].url+"</td>";
  html +="<td>"+json.person[i].upvotes+"</td>";
  html +="</tr>";
  $('table tbody').append(html);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Author</th>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Url</th>
      <th>Upvotes</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: vlw vou tentar aqui

Comment: Se realmente ajudar, marca como resposta valeu? Abraços e boa sorte!

Comment: aliás fazendo isso não precisa do javascript?

Comment: Sim, precisa! Inclusive, é ele que ta pegando as informações do Json e jogando no HTML

Answer (score -1):

Para filtrar os dados você pode usar [`search`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_search.asp):

```
//Sintaxe:
var teste = 'exemplo'
teste.search('ex') //Retorna 0 que é a posição da primeira ocorrência do filtro
teste.search('Ex') //Retorna -1, ou seja, não foi encontrado
teste.search(/Ex/i) //Exemplo de busca com case-insensitive, retorna 0 

//No JSON, para buscar os autores que tenham a letra y ou Y:
for(var i = 0; i < json.person.length; i++) {
    if(json.person[i].author.search(/y/i) != -1) {
        //Mostra os dados
    }
}
```

Para cadastrar use [`push`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp):

```
//Sintaxe
var exemplo = [1, 2, 3]
exemplo.push(4)
console.log(exemplo) //Retorna [1, 2, 3, 4]

//Você pode usar push para adicionar objetos no JSON
json.person.push({
    author: 'nome exemplo',
    title: 'exemplo de titulp',
    url: 'https://google.com',
    category: 'minha categoria',
    comments: 0,
    created_at: 1460030400,
    upvotes: 0
})
//push() retorna o índice do cadastro, no caso 8
```

[Leia mais sobre arrays](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_array_methods.asp)

Comment: vlw mano vou dar uma estudada

Comment: A resposta não ajuda a responder a pergunta. O mais indicado é colocar em um comentário, mesmo assim não sei em que ajudaria.

Comment: @FilipeMoraes Que resposta, minha ou do Guilherme?

Comment: @user4451 O seu foi um comentário, por tanto estou a falar do resposta do Guilherme.

Comment: @FilipeMoraes a pergunta principal é sobre o erro, mas ele também pede referencias sobre manipulação de JSON, porque isso não é uma resposta?

Comment: Utilize o comentário para isso. A resposta deve ser completa e não parcial.

Comment: @FilipeMoraes mesmo se outra resposta anterior ja sanou a outra metade? sendo desnecessário repetição do mesmo

Comment: Eu não sei se é uma regra aqui do stack, mas acho que não tem necessidade desta discussão, mesmo que ele não tenha colocado outra parte eu agradeço, pois pra quem está perdido toda ajuda é bem vinda!!

Comment: Embora este link possa responder à pergunta, é melhor incluir as partes essenciais da resposta aqui e fornecer o link para referência.  As respostas apenas por link podem ser invalidadas se a página com o link for alterada. - [Da Revisão](/review/low-quality-posts/156288)

Comment: É nisso vc tem razão

Comment: @rLinhares concordo com isso apesar de achar difícil a w3s mudar seus links, por isso editei a pergunta com um exemplo

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam Eu tentei usar os dados que passou mas não consegui, fiz um update usando o código que postei, só que o problema que ele só é perfeito se o código estiver diretamente no HTML e não trazido do jason.

Comment: Se o erro acontece apenas quando o arquivo é externo ao html o erro esta em carregar o mesmo, de uma olhada nessa [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/268692/como-incluir-e-manipular-arquivo-json-local), se o problema persistir avise

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam Eu coloquei outro código lá no post principal que agora dá certo, só falta agora eu filtrar por categoria e pronto.

Comment: Crie outra pergunta, não use a mesma se esse problema foi resolvido

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam Sim, é que as vezes fico meio com receio de fazer isso, dai dizerem que estou sendo redundante e fecharem meu post