# Como receber dados JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Eu quero recuperar um código JSON para HTML com jQuery.
Como posso fazer isso? E como eu posso usar o CSS com os dados JSON?

Aqui está o código JSON.

```
    {
    "quiz": {
        "sport": {
            "q1": {
                "question": "Which one is correct team name in NBA?",
                "options": [
                    "New York Bulls",
                    "Los Angeles Kings",
                    "Golden State Warriros",
                    "Huston Rocket"
                ],
                "answer": "Huston Rocket"
            }
        },
        "maths": {
            "q1": {
                "question": "5 + 7 = ?",
                "options": [
                    "10",
                    "11",
                    "12",
                    "13"
                ],
                "answer": "12"
            },
            "q2": {
                "question": "12 - 8 = ?",
                "options": [
                    "1",
                    "2",
                    "3",
                    "4"
                ],
                "answer": "4"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Onde está esse JSON? Você precisa recebê-lo via AJAX?

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow em português! O que você tentou?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Seria bom sem AJAX, pois estou tendo problemas com a instalação do WinLamp.
A pasta do código está no desktop, tendo em vista os problemas com web server.

Comment: @TomásBarcellos Tentei utilizar de arquivos js para coletar a informação da json para a html, porém nenhum foi efetivo.

Comment: Então quer ler o arquivo em disco com o JavaScript? Isso não é possível. Você precisará se um servidor web servindo o arquivo e obtê-lo com uma requisição HTTP.

Comment: Dê uma olhada em AXIOS https://github.com/axios/axios e VueJS https://br.vuejs.org/
 Se quiser posso fazer um exemplo e postar como resposta.

Comment: Qual a URL e método que gera este `JSON` ?

Comment: @Tony Nunca vi sobre AXIOS, se puder gostaria de um exemplo.

Comment: @Tony Este arquivo JSON não foi construído por mim...

Comment: @JoãoVitor dá uma lida na documentação do Axios. 

Um exemplo de utilização seria.

`axios.get(http://suaurl/).
 then(response => { 
   //Aqui você pega a resposta e trata ela
})
.catch(err => {
 // Aqui trata algum erro na resposta
});`

Comment: Você pode colocar aqui a URL que retorna este JSON ?

Comment: O que o pessoal quis dizer e que vc tem q ter uma fonte pra obter esse resultado, seja uma string, uma URL ou um arquivo. De qualquer forma, pra usar no Javascript vc precisar servir ele pois por limitação de segurança o JS nao permite q vc leia um arquivo por ele.

Comment: Achei uma alternativa aqui com uns membros, peço desculpas pelas idiotices minhas, é o meu primeiro post oficialmente no stack [que já ficou bem óbvio].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para receber JSON você pode usar o AXIOS ao invés do jQuery com o comando `axios.get`.
Para integrar com a interface HTML e CSS você pode usar o VueJS.

Use este exemplo completo que montei usando HTML, JavaScript, VueJS e AXIOS:

Clique: [Ver Json usando HTML](https://exemplos.azurewebsites.net/VerJson.html)

Crie um arquivo **VerJson.html** e coloque este conteúdo:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Exemplo JSON</title>

        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
        <!-- Mobile viewport optimized: h5bp.com/viewport -->
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous" />

        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="app">
          <h1>{{ message }}</h1><br>

          Versão:<br>
          {{dados.version}}<br>

          Dados:<br>
          <div v-for="detalhe in dados.data">
            Nome:{{detalhe.name}}<br>
            Descricao:{{detalhe.description}}<br>
            <img :src="detalhe.picture" >
            <hr>
          </div>
        </div>

        <script>
        var app = new Vue(
                    {
                        el: '#app',
                        data: 
                        {
                            message: 'Hello Vue!',
                            dados: {}
                        },
                        mounted() 
                        {
                            axios.get("https://exemplos.azurewebsites.net/r7.json.txt").then(response => 
                            { 
                                //Aqui você pega a resposta e trata ela 
                                app.dados = response.data;
                            }).catch(err => 
                            { 
                                // Aqui trata algum erro na resposta 
                                alert(err);
                            });
                            // alert('mounted()');
                        }
                    });
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou aqui, agora só falta usar o css apra arrumar, mas ajudou muito.
Desculpe pelas perguntas bobas haha.

Comment: Valeu! Deixei o link no Head para o Boostrap 4, agora é com você! http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/overview/

Answer (score 0):

Usando jQuery, vc pode usar a função jQuery.ajax para receber o json e manipula-lo.

No server side, supondo que seria PHP, haveria algo do tipo um array com os dados, digamos $data. Monte uma URL que retorne json_encode($data), passando um header content type: application/json.

```
header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
return json_encode($data);
```

No Javascript, chamaria:

```
jQuery.ajax({
   url: 'url do script php q retorna o json(acima)',
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function (response) {
       alert(response[0].name);
   }
});
```

Comment: Outra maneira muito útil também, pretendo usar também. Obrigado, amigo