# Gerar JSON a partir de uma URL e Pesquisar por localização

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json

Boa note a todos, gostaria de saber se há alguma possibilidade de mostrar uma lista JSON a partir de uma URL sendo que nessa mesma url geram os seguintes valores: **nmConveniado**, **listaEspecialidade**, **listaEndereco**.

Tentei usar o seguinte script mas não obtive êxito:

```
<script>

// Users data in json format
var userData = URL: "http://url.com/arquivo.json" };
// user's input for search
var searchVal = '';

$(function(){
      // if text box value is not null, then darken reset icon
      $(".slinput input").keyup(function(){
        var val = $(this).val();   
        if(val.length > 0) {
           $(this).parent().find(".right-icon").css('color','#555');
        } else {
          $(this).parent().find(".right-icon").css('color','#ccc');
        }
      });

      // if user click on reset icon, clear text field
      $(".slinput .right-icon").click(function(){
        $(this).parent().find("input").val('');
        $(this).css('color','#ccc');
        loadData(userData);
      });

      loadData(userData);
});

// Displaying Information to Users
function loadData(data) {
    var htmlData = '';
    $.each(data, function(index, val){
        htmlData += '<div class="media user">'+
        '  <div class="media-left">'+
        '    <a href="#">'+
        '      <img class="media-object" src="'+val.listaImagem+'" alt="...">'+
        '    </a>'+
        '  </div>'+
        '  <div class="media-body">'+
        '    <h4 class="media-heading">'+val.nmConveniado+'</h4>'+
        '    '+val.place+
        '  </div>'+
        '</div>';
    });
    $("#users").html(htmlData);
}

// Search users data based input search keyword
function searchUsers() {
    var val = $("#searchInput").val();
    if(val == searchVal) {
        return; 
    } else {
        searchVal = val;
        var searchResults = {};
        searchResults = [];
        $.each(userData, function(i, v) {
            if (v.nmConveniado.toLowerCase().indexOf(val) != -1) {
                searchResults.push(v);  
            }
        });
        loadData(searchResults);    
    }
}
</script>
```

No mesmo arquivo vou tentar filtrar a lista por nome, cidade, categoria.

Comment: Dê uma olhada nesta resposta que acabei de dar, diga se serve, posso ajustar ela e responder aqui na sua pergunta. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/308311/5704

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa começar chamando a URL via ajax, `var userData = URL: "http://url.com/arquivo.json" };` não vai funcionar, com jQuery fica assim:

```
 var userData = '';

 $.ajax({
    url: "http://url.com/arquivo.json",
    success: function (json) {
        userData = JSON.parse(json);
    },
    error: function (xhr) {
        console.log(xhr);
    }
});
```

O que fazemos aqui é chamar a URL e pegar a resposta em `success`, no caso bem sucedido, ou em `error`, caso de algum problema. A função em `success` vai parsear o retorno da URL e salvar na variável `userData` como um objeto.